# How to Send same file/different file multiple times to server with "form data" using Postman or Jmeter?

Tags: forms, jmeter, postman, form-data

For Example, I want to send a file multiple times to the server concurrently/Sequentially with "form data" request.
I can able to send single file at once which reflects in the server.
**-**I want to send this file for 10000 times concurrently/Sequentially to the server.
**-**If possible, i want to know send different files at once.
Jmeter or POSTMAN anything is fine. I just want it to be done.
Thanks in advance.

[screenshot for one file upload at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Ths.png)Please find the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For JMeter:

1. Record your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

   - Start JMeter's proxy server
   - Configure your browser (or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy)) to use JMeter as a proxy
   - Copy the file you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
   - Perform the upload in browser (or Postman) - JMeter will record the request
2. In order to execute 10k concurrent uploads:

   - Set "Number of Threads" in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to `10000`
   - Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the HTTP Request which performs the upload and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `10000`
3. To upload different files you can substitute hard-coded recorded file name with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from i.e. [Directory Listing Config Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. Thanks for your reply. The thing is, we cannot record the file upload request because it is sending from a Wi-Fi device. In this case what to do... Thanks in advance

Comment: If the Wi-Fi device and the host where you running JMeter are on the same network - it should be OK to record. If not and there is no possibility to amend network configuration you can try a 3rd-party recording service i.e. [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-)